# Scheme - function that returns a growing list

Tags: list, scheme

I could not find a similar problem here, but I'm trying to write a program in scheme for a class so hints would be very well appreciated! I'm basically confused as to how to implement this but here is an example on how it's supposed to work. `(index 5)` is supposed to return the list `(1 2 3 4 5)`. I have a couple of ideas, could they work?

1. I make the argument a global variable which I increment each time I call the function recursively. the problem I've had with this so far is that using set! returns a list but the output would look something like this (#value #value....)
2. program a simple recursive function that gives the list (5 4 3 2 1) and then reverse it, but would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with solution 2 as it is by far the cleanest, least complicated option. You just need to figure out the recursion. Hint: the base case is reached at `(index 0)`, which should return the empty list. Reversing afterward can be done by putting actual recursion in a helper function:

```
(define (index-r n)
  ...)

(define (index n)
  (reverse (index-r n)))
```

(Or use a named-`let` loop.)

Comment: thanks lars! wasn't aware that there was an inbuilt reverse function in scheme

Answer (score 0):

> program a simple recursive function that gives the list (5 4 3 2 1) and then reverse it, but would i be able to do that?

Why not directly write a recursive function that gives the list (1 2 3 4 5) ??
In "pseudo code" so that I don't do it for you:

```
f(x) = cons x (f(x+1))
f(5) = (list 5)
```

and then, call `f(1)`…